# Layout issue Material UI and React

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, material-ui

I would like to get some help on React and Material UI.

My goal is to have 3 columns on desktop, one with a radio button and a label inline and inside the two others columns a select menu with some option values.

On Mobile i need to have just two columns with the select menu inside and the input needs to go above the 2 columns
Something like this.
The first picture shows the desktop layout ( 3 columns with the same size ) , the second picture the mobile layout ( 2 columns and 2 rows )

[Desktop Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bGik.jpg)

[Mobile Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJb0h.jpg)

For the moment I am getting 3 columns on my layout but i am stuck on the mobile version.
Still learning react and material ui , i will appreciate any help.

```
<Grid display='flex>
    <Grid lg={4}
            <FormControlLabel value="my quantity" control={<Radio />} label="My Label" />
    </Grid>
    <Grid lg={4}>
        <InputLabel  htmlFor="uncontrolled-native" sx={{ display:'inline-block'}}>Text One</InputLabel>
        <Select defaultValue={4} sx={{ backgroundColor:'lightgrey'}}>
        <option value={1}>1</option>
        </Select>  
    </Grid>
    <Grid lg={4}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="uncontrolled-native" sx={{ display:'inline-block'}}>Text Two</InputLabel>
        <Select>
        <option value={1}>1</option>
        </Select>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Thanks
Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Basically Grid has a total of 12 columns, so let's say you want 1 column to have 2 elements you should divide the 12/2 which is 6 per element. Here is an example of your case:

```
    <Grid container spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={12} lg={6}>
        <Item>Your label (1)</Item>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} lg={6}>
        <Stack direction="row" spacing={2}>
          <Item>Text 1</Item>
          <Item>Text 2</Item>
        </Stack>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```